# $\sum_{x=a}^{b-1}\frac{1}{x}$ and $\sum_{x=a+1}^b\frac{1}{x}$

Tags: integration, summation, logarithms, relations

I have to prove the following relations:

- $\sum_{x=a}^{b-1}\frac{1}{x}\geq\log b - \log a $
- $\sum_{x=a+1}^{b}\frac{1}{x}\leq\log b - \log a $

I tried to use the relation that $\int_a^b \frac{1}{x} dx = \log b - \log a$ and for the second relation I obtained that $\int_{a+1}^b \frac{1}{x} dx = \log b - \log (a+1) < \log b - \log a$ and I think that could be sufficient to prove the relation. Instead, for the first relation i have some problems, because using the same method I don't obtain a good result, indeed:
$ \int_{a}^{b-1} \frac{1}{x} dx = \log (b-1) - \log a$ that is not greater than $\log b - \log a$. What do you think? How can I resolve it?

Comment: Are $a$ and $b$ supposed to be integers?

Comment: yes, they are integers

Comment: I think you mixed up "second relation" with "first relation" when saying "Insead, for the second relation i have some problems".

Comment: you have right, i have just edit it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, welcome to MSE, and great opening post!

Here's my hints on how to analyze this problem:

Consider left hand and right hand sums of $\frac{1}{x}$. For our first inequality we are using lefthand sums with width of $1$, so then, by the shape of the graph $\frac{1}{x}$ we get an overestimation of the integral so that
$$
\sum_{x=a}^{b-1} \frac{1}{x} \ge \int_a^b \frac{1}{x} \, \mathrm{d} x
$$

Do you see what to do for the second example?

As for your approach to the problem, you were close, realizing that $\int_{a+1}^b \frac{1}{x} \, \mathrm{d} x \le \int_a^b \frac{1}{x} \, \mathrm{d} x$ is similar to what I'm doing - it just seems like you were one step away!

Comment: Thanks for your welcome! I've partially understand you're answer. The things that i don't understand so much is how can I exactly say that i overstimate the summatory with that integral?

Comment: @theboss do you follow what I mean by left hand sum? If so, draw out $\frac{1}{x}$ on a graph, and then for some arbitrary integer endpoints $a,b$ create left riemann sums with width of $1$ and then you can see that the total area by these rectangles is exactly the summation, and that this area is clearly larger than the area beneath the line $\frac{1}{x}$ from $a \to b$.

Comment: @theboss what I mean by drawing the graph can be seen in an example [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum#Methods).

Comment: ah okok, now it's clear! Thank you very much!